# Why is the function open_tx executed twice for each transfer command?

Tags: monero-wallet-cli, source, transfer, transaction-key

I built a private testnet with reference to [this guide](https://github.com/moneroexamples/private-testnet).

In order to understand how the secret transaction key is generated, I examined how many times the `open_tx` function (in [device_default.cpp](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/master/src/device/device_default.cpp)) was executed with a transfer command from the monero-wallet-cli. `open_tx` is the function used in `construct_tx_and_get_tx_key` function (in [cryptonote_tx_utils.cpp](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/release-v0.15/src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_tx_utils.cpp)) to generate a secret transaction key.

It turned out that `open_tx` was executed twice per one transfer command. Why is `open_tx` executed twice instead of once?

Answer (score 2):

In short, *tests*.

You can see this by following the path taken by the CLI wallet when doing a transfer, as you essentially end up in [create_transactions_2](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/b4e1dc83d275f8ee9a8c12615cf952f05161c7a3/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L9376). If you follow through that, you will see [transfer_selected_rct](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/b4e1dc83d275f8ee9a8c12615cf952f05161c7a3/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L8479) gets called from various places ([1](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/b4e1dc83d275f8ee9a8c12615cf952f05161c7a3/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L9766)/[2](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/b4e1dc83d275f8ee9a8c12615cf952f05161c7a3/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L9809) & [3](https://github.com/monero-project/monero/blob/b4e1dc83d275f8ee9a8c12615cf952f05161c7a3/src/wallet/wallet2.cpp#L9874)), and it's that which makes calls through to `open_tx` via `construct_tx_and_get_tx_key`. Thus a *test* tx performed in `create_transactions_2` will call through to `open_tx`, as will the final real one.